# Coldfusion createobject throws error with https service url

Tags: web-services, https, coldfusion

I have following coldfusion client code which invokes a https wcf based service exposed as plain basicHttpBinding.

```
  <cfscript>
 ws = CreateObject("webservice", "https://testserver.secureservice.svc?wsdl");  
 result = ws.PostData("testdata");   
</cfscript>
<cfoutput>  
   SOAP Return value: #result#<br>      
</cfoutput>
```

but when i excute the service it throws the following error:

> Unable to read WSDL from URL:
>   https://testserver.secureservice.svc?wsdl.
>   Error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: Could not build a
>   validated path.. It is recommended that you use a web browser to
>   retrieve and examine the requested WSDL document to ensure it is
>   correct.

but the same service works from SoapUI tool.

what am i missing?

Comment: Have you imported the SSL cert for that domain so CF can use it?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue with the link below:

http://coldfusion-tip.blogspot.in/2012/04/javaxnetsslsslpeerunverifiedexception.html